# AutoMapper, InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Byte]' to type 'Google.Protobuf.ByteString'

Tags: protocol-buffers, automapper

I am new to AutoMapper.

I am retrieving Ink Strokes from a database as a byte[] and then trying to serialize these to  a Google.ProtoBuf.ByteString.

I consistently get the Error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Byte]' to type
> 'Google.Protobuf.ByteString'.

Here is what I have:

In the Protobuf file:

```
message LoadInkResponse {
    bytes Strokes  =1;
}
```

In my domain model:

```
public class LoadInkResponse
    {
        public byte[] Strokes { get; set; }
    }
```

And, lastly, in the AutoMapperProfile.cs ,

```
CreateMap<Model.Models.ProgressNotesModel.LoadInkResponse, LoadInkResponse>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Strokes, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ByteString.CopyFrom(src.Strokes)));
```

where ByteString.CopyFrom is from the Google.Protobuf assembly.

All my attempts at converting the domain byte[] to the DTO ByteString have failed with the same error message.

How is this done????

TIA.

Comment: Upgrade AutoMapper.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have the version put out one year ago. I need help with the mapping conversion. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with your mapping is that you're using a value resolver when in fact a type converter fits better.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting here, @Lucian Bargaoanu, is correct. All my attempts at using a "ForMember" value resolver failed.

However, creating this simple type converter works.

```
public class ByteStringTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<byte[], ByteString>
    {
        public ByteString Convert(byte[] source, ByteString destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return ByteString.CopyFrom(source);
        }
    }

 CreateMap<byte[], ByteString>().ConvertUsing(new ByteStringTypeConverter());
 CreateMap<Model.Models.ProgressNotesModel.LoadInkResponse, LoadInkResponse>();
```

Comment: You can simply write `.ConvertUsing(source => ByteString.CopyFrom(source));`.